# Переключение GIL в python 2.x и python 3.x

Tags: python

Переключение в версии 2.х понятно, раз в 100 тиков происходит проверка на переключение потока.
В версии 3.х тики убраны, теперь всё базируется на времени. Как построена логика переключения в версии 3.х?

Comment: Я бы не был столь категоричен насчет понятности переключения каждые 100 тиков или 5 мс в версии 3.2, в который GIL был подвергнут изменениям. Самое понятное объяснение, что я видел можно почитать [тут](http://www.dabeaz.com/python/NewGIL.pdf).

Comment: @m9_psy спасибо, ознакомлюсь. Все же, где я ни читал - везде информация про 100 тиков

Answer (score 1):

Если быть точным, то реализация GIL изменилась в версии 3.2

В python < 3.2 переключение действительно происходило каждые 100 инструкций - [хороший перевод статьи](https://habrahabr.ru/post/84629/) от Дэвида Бизли

Если говорить о python > 3.2, то суть такая. С одной стороны поток не отдает GIL пока его не попросят. С другой стороны, если GIL захвачен, то поток сначала подождет некоторое время (5мс, sys.getcheckinterval) - а потом уже просит освободить GIL. Получается, что переключение происходит не чаще, чем раз в 5 мс.

Достаточно хорошо этот момент осветил пресловутый Дэвид Бизли (в комментариях [@m9_psy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/642814/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-gil-%D0%B2-python-2-x-%D0%B8-python-3-x/662276#comment913533_642814) дал ссылку на презентацию), и не менее пресловутый Андрей Светлов в [своем блоге](http://asvetlov.blogspot.ru/2011/07/gil.html)